# Select2 issue when deleting the search term(ajax request)

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Following the example page of [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax).

There is a minimum input length of 1. When I type `AA`, get the results, then delete `AA`, I still get results for `A`.

It looks like select2 ignores the `minimumInputLength` settings when deleting the search term and shows results even though I have deleted the search term.

Is there any event triggered when the search term is changed? Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

That is not an issue of `minimum length`. What you actually see is the default behaviour of select2 caching. When you type in your first text, select2 will fetch the options, but it will keep them in DOM, when you delete the text, so you will see them after you delete the text and open options. To disable this you need to add `cache: false` option

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with caching. The problem happens because it started the ajax request when i deleted "AA" to "A" and then to "". It made a request for "A". When it got the response it just showed the results even thought the text was already ""

Answer (score 0):

This situation have a relationship with the parameter "tag". Please set `tags: false`, in your `select2`.